# Troubles when launching Hello World : unsatisfiedlinkerror with dalvik system?

Tags: android, cocos2d-x

I am trying my first hello world project, I am following ray wenderlich's tutorial, but I have got this error :

java lang unsatisfiedlinkerror couldn't load game from loader dalvik.system...

my error :
[image]

Would you know how to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: please go to ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/platforms/YOUR_PLATFORM_VERSION, then check if the "Image" folder is exist? if not, install another API for SDK

Answer (score 0):

your `libgame.so` file might be missing under `project->libs->armeabi->libgame.so`. libgame.so file is generate when you click the create-android-project.bat in windows or create-android-project.sh in linux/mac.